# PageRank Equation

Tags: probability, algorithms

I've been trying to study the PageRank algorithm and from this [website](http://pr.efactory.de/e-pagerank-algorithm.shtml), I have a problem understanding on how to solve the following equation:

> PR(A) = 0.5 + 0.5 PR(C)
>
> PR(B) = 0.5 + 0.5 (PR(A) / 2)
>
> PR(C) = 0.5 + 0.5 (PR(A) / 2 + PR(B))
>
> These equations can easily be solved. We get the following PageRank values for the single pages:
>
> PR(A) = 14/13 = 1.07692308
>
> PR(B) = 10/13 = 0.76923077
>
> PR(C) = 15/13 = 1.15384615

If PR(A), PR(B) and PR(C) are unknowns, how did they end up with the fractions without doing iterative computation? Did they solve using linear equation? Can someone explain to me step-by-step on how to reach these values? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is just three linear equations in three unknowns and can be solved using standard linear algebra methods. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: That's what I thought. I've been reading a lot on pagerank examples and I'm always stuck on this step. Please if you could kindly explain step-by-step how to reach the values for PR(A), PR(B) and PR(C) above using linear algebra @Casteels. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I mean, do you know about row reduction techniques? Can you solve a system of two equations in two unknowns?

Comment: Is that what it's called Gaussian elimination? I haven't come across it before. Pls help. @Casteels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One gets a system of three equations in three unknowns:
$$PR(A)=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}PR(C)\\PR(B)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}PR(A)\\ PR(C)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}PR(A)+\frac{1}{2}PR(B).$$

In matrix form we want to solve $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{4} & 1 & 0\\-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}PR(A)\\PR(B)\\PR(C)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Applying standard row reduction ([Gaussian elimination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j5Ic2V7wq4)) methods leads to the given solution $PR(A)=\frac{14}{13}$, $PR(B)=\frac{10}{13}$ and $PR(C)=\frac{15}{13}$.

---

Equivalently (but uglier) you can just work with your equations. Plugging in the first equation for $PR(A)$ into the second you get the equation $$PR(B)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}PR(C)=\frac{5}{8}+\frac{1}{8}PR(C).$$ Plugging in this equation and the first equation into the third you get $$PR(C)=\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}PR(C)+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{16}PR(C).$$ Solving this for $PR(C)$ gets you $PR(C)=\frac{15}{13}$. Now you can plug this value for $PR(C)$ back into your other equations to get $PR(A)$ and $PR(B)$.